# R How to transfer date from one dataframe to another?

Tags: r, date

I want to transfer `date.onset.index` from `data.hh` to `data.hh2`,
However, when I did the transfer, it became a integer/value.

Could any expert give me a hand? THANK YOU!

```
data.hh
hhID date.onset.index   date.recruitment    onsettime
 1   2008-01-08           2008-01-09         2
 2   2008-01-10           2008-01-11         3
 3   2008-01-12           2008-01-14         4

hkdata
hhID member  onset.secondary    date.onset.index    
 1      1      2008-01-15             13388    
 1      2      2008-01-14             13388
 2      1      2008-01-17             13390
 2      2      2008-01-18             13390
```

Here is the code that I used:

```
for(i in 1:length(hkdata$hhID))
{
  hkdata$date.onset.index[i]=data.hh$date.onset.index[which(data.hh$hhID==hkdata$hhID[i])]
}

hkdata$date.onset.index= as.character(hkdata$date.onset.index)
hkdata$date.onset.index= as.Date(hkdata$date.onset.index,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I want to get output like this :)

```
hkdata
hhID member  onset.secondary    date.onset.index    
 1      1      2008-01-15             2008-01-08       
 1      2      2008-01-14             2008-01-08
 2      1      2008-01-17             2008-01-10
 2      2      2008-01-18             2008-01-10
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `merge` function.

Comment: 1- I don't think your code aligns with the data set names you specified. 2- It would be easier to help you if you will specify your desired results, as be assured that no "expert" will advise to use the loop in the first place

Comment: Please help me! I have just revised the coding..

Comment: I cant really mege them cause they have different rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to merge the two data set and the code worked

```
Temp= merge(hkdata, hhID)
```

You will get back 7 variables (only 1 column is in common)

```
str(Temp)

 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ hhID            : int  1 1 2 2
 $ member          : int  1 2 1 2
 $ onsetsecondary  : Date, format: "2008-01-15" "2008-01-14" "2008-01-17" ...
 $ dateonsetindex  : num  13388 13388 13390 13390
 $ date.onset.index: Date, format: "2008-01-08" "2008-01-08" "2008-01-10" ...
 $ date.recruitment: Date, format: "2008-01-09" "2008-01-09" "2008-01-11" ...
 $ onsettime       : int  2 2 3 3

Temp
 hhID member onsetsecondary dateonsetindex date.onset.index date.recruitment onsettime
1    1      1     2008-01-15          13388       2008-01-08       2008-01-09         2
2    1      2     2008-01-14          13388       2008-01-08       2008-01-09         2
3    2      1     2008-01-17          13390       2008-01-10       2008-01-11         3
4    2      2     2008-01-18          13390       2008-01-10       2008-01-11         3
```

then you only need to select the columns you want.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi @user3848693 if my answer worked for you, you are supposed to mark it as the right answer and/or upvote it. In this way it will be visible for all the user that the question has been answered correctly.